# Webscraping output []

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hey i just wanted to test Python Webscraping and i have no Idea why this doesn't work.
As output i become [] and nothing else.
Has anyone an Idea? BEcause if i go to the Website and search for the element i find it.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html_text = requests.get("https://osu.ppy.sh/users/20488254").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "lxml")
job = soup.find("div", class_ = "profile-detail__col profile-detail__col--bottom-right")
print(job)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Player info is loaded dynamically with JS. So, you can't scrape dynamic content using plain `bs4`. Luckily, they provide user info in json format inside script tag. If you open page source and look for `json-user` you will see there is a tag:

```
<script id="json-user" type="application/json">
{"avatar_url":"https:\/\/a.ppy.sh\/20488254?1622470835.jpeg","country_code":"AT","default_group":"default","id":20488254,...
</script>
```

You can grab json inside that tag and get any information about player. Here is how it would look like:

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_text = requests.get("https://osu.ppy.sh/users/20488254").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "lxml")

json_data = json.loads(soup.find('script', {'id':'json-user'}).string)
```

Now let's say you are looking for player's global rank. All you need to do is to find the correct keys to navigate you there:

```
player_rank = json_data['statistics']['global_rank']
# -> 199303
```